# Webservice to aggregate the online services I use

Tags: webapp-rec, links

I'm searching for a simple webservice to aggregate and show the online services I use. I just want to have one link to post and a user who follows it will see all the services I use. Like my Blog, Twitter, Facebook, Dribbble, Grooveshark, you name it.

Of course there are other ways to achieve it, like setting up a blog, but isn't there a simple service which I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend **[flavors.me](http://flavors.me/)**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

https://about.me/

> quickly build your personal profile page that points users to your content from around the web.

Hope this helps.